# Apply formulas to row when the new one is added

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdLwp8Cyv31KTz0R7UXIaeOBoJAfkRSXgbzIJMICPKXBQ6tZQ/viewform) that is submitted to the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14NmTXg24iVty-AXNJBfyPdcoHT3gUQYUH6jAdXdF2dY/edit?usp=sharing).

In that spreadsheet I've added a second sheet `Results` where I want to organize processed view of results. But when the form is submitted, the new row is inserted into the `Ответы на форму (1)` sheet. The problem is that such rows are not handled on the `Results` sheet.

So how can I handle form submits if I want processed rows to appear automatically?

[image: Filling diagram]

PS: Feel free to clone `Results` sheet for your experiments.
You can edit the document except of 2 sheets (`Ответы на форму (1)` and `Results`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `arrayformula` syntax for such operations. Simple copying from one sheet to another:

```
=arrayformula(Source!C:C)
```

Processing all E column (starting with 2nd row), marking + if the content of D1 is found:

```
=arrayformula(if(isnumber(find(D1, E2:E)), "+", ""))
```